# Related Rates: rate of change of the speed of sound with respect to temperature.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, physics

The speed of sound, v, in air is a function of the temperature, T, of the air:

$v = 331.4 + 0.6(T − 273)$

with v in meters per second and T in kelvins

Suppose the rate of change of air temperature is $-0.11 \frac{K}{min}$.

1. Find the rate of change of the speed of sound with respect to time.
2. **Find the rate of change of the speed of sound with respect to temperature.**

---

I found the answer to part one by taking the derivative of the original function:

- $ v'= 0.6(T')$
- $v'=0.6(-0.11)$
- $v'= -0.066 \frac{m/s}{min}$

What I know about part two:

- Units are in $\frac{m/K}{min}$
- $0.6$ is in units of $\frac{m/s}{K}$

What I have tried:

- Since I know the units are in $\frac{m/K}{min}$ , I hypothesized changing the units of $-0.11 \frac{K}{min}$ into $\frac{K}{s}$ in order to cancel out the unit of $s$ to arrive at units in $\frac{m/K}{min}$
- $v'=0.6 \frac{m/s}{K}\cdot-0.0011 \frac{K}{s}$
- $v' = -0.00066$

This is not the correct answer. Can someone put me on the right track to arrive at $\frac{m/K}{min}$? Is my hypothesis wrong?

Comment: You have an equation for $v$ as a function of $T$. If I gave you $y$ as a function of $x$ and asked you for the rate of change of $y$ with respect to $x$, what would you do?

Comment: @rogerl  From what I understand, this means how fast y is changing in comparison to x, but I am unsure how to use this information. Do I need an equation relating v' and T' that is different than the one I have?